# Seg fault linked list recursion in C

Tags: c, recursion, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I can't figure out why I'm seg faulting. The basic idea is to insert integers in order recursively using a linked list.

```
node* insert(node** head, int integer)
{
    node* temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
    node* temp1;
    node* newNode;

    if(*head == NULL)
    {
        temp->num = integer;
        temp->next = *head;
        *head = temp;
    }
    else if((*head)->num > integer)
    {
        temp = *head;
        temp1 = temp->next; //breaks the link
        temp->next = newNode;   //creates a new node
        newNode->num = integer;  //adds int
        newNode->next = temp1;   //links new node to previously broken node 
        temp1->next = *head; //next node is NULL 
        *head = temp1;  //Makes next node head again
    }

    else
        insert(&((*head)->next), integer);

    return(temp);
}
```

I ran this code in GDB and it seg faults at `temp1->next = *head` but I don't understand why. I even put notes to help myself but I guess it isn't working. Can someone please tell me why I'm seg faulting? Thanks.

Comment: What's the value of `head` before the segmentation fault? (`head`, not`*head`). I ask that, because it could be the source of the segmentation fault: dereferencing a null pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
temp1 = temp->next;
```

should be before

```
temp = *head;
```

In case that the `(*head)->num > integer` and If you want to insert the integer in the header than your code is complicated and wrong. you can do it in this way:

```
else if((*head)->num > integer)
    {
        temp->next = *head;
        temp->num = integer;
        *head = temp;
    }
```

and the

```
temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
```

should be called only into the

```
if(*head == NULL)
```

and into

```
else if((*head)->num > integer)
```

So your final function could be like this

```
node* insert(node** head, int integer)
{
    node* temp;

    if(*head == NULL)
    {
        temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp->num = integer;
        temp->next = *head;
        *head = temp;
    }
    else if((*head)->num > integer)
    {
        temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp->next = *head;
        temp->num = integer;
        *head = temp;
    }

    else
        temp = insert(&((*head)->next), integer);

    return(temp);
}
```

I test the insert function with:

```
int main (void) {


   node *tmp, *head = NULL;
   insert(&head, 5);
   insert(&head, 7);
   insert(&head, 3);
   insert(&head, 6);
   insert(&head, 4);
   insert(&head, 2);

   for (tmp = head; tmp!=NULL; tmp = tmp->next) {
        printf("tmp->num  %d\n",tmp->num);
   }

}
```

and it works succefully!

```
$ ./test
tmp->num  2
tmp->num  3
tmp->num  4
tmp->num  5
tmp->num  6
tmp->num  7
```

Comment: Thanks alot.. I really screwed up my else if statement. It's the recursion that really through me off. I was trying to insert in the middle of the link list but I forgot I was traversing it and I didn't have to have all the extra variables.

Answer (score 2):

So the first time you go through this, head is null and you've got a case for that.

The next time through, head has a pointer, and there is no next node. The head->next  is NULL.

So when you get to:

```
temp1 = temp->next;
```

That's setting it equal to NULL. And when you get to

```
temp1->next = *head; //next node is NULL
```

Whoa there, temp1 is null. There is no such thing as temp1->next, that's looking for a structure where there is none.

**Edit:**
And you're throwing away the memory you just allocated when you set `temp = *head`. You probably shouldn't be allocating memory until you're sure you need it. I mean, you call a new instance of `insert()` every time the number is less than the target. Each pass you allocate some memory that you don't actually use. And you probably wanted to allocate memory for `newnode`, not `temp`.

And you should probably use a better naming scheme. I mean, the second time you call insert, it's no longer the head. `integer` could be something more like `intToInsert` or `newValue`. `temp1` is more like `savedTail`. Minor issue, but it helps keep things straight, and it's a good habit to get into.

Finally, think about what happens when you've gone through the list, found where the new item belongs, made a new node, set it's `->next` field to the rest of the tail, and returned.   ... now what? the previous node has a `next` value that's still pointing to what it was before. You need to update that link as well.

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume that the linked list currently has only one node.

So *head = some node.

*head->next = NULL.

Now lets look into the code:

```
node* insert(node** head, int integer)
{
    node* temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
    node* temp1;
    node* newNode;

    if(*head == NULL)  // condition = false
    {
        temp->num = integer;
        temp->next = *head;
        *head = temp;
    }
    else if((*head)->num > integer)  // let's assume condition = true
    {
        temp = *head;
        temp1 = temp->next; //breaks the link   // temp1 = NULL
        temp->next = newNode;   //creates a new node  // temp1 is not changed
        newNode->num = integer;  //adds int
        newNode->next = temp1;   //links new node to previously broken node 
        temp1->next = *head; //next node is NULL // NULL->next !!!
        *head = temp1;  //Makes next node head again
    }

    else
        insert(&((*head)->next), integer);

    return(temp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
*head = temp1;
```

should be before

```
temp1->next = *head;
```